# Pinch Gesture Recognizer Delay on Device

Tags: xcode, zooming, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have put a pinch gesture recognizer in my app.  It works fine on the simulator.  But there is a very long delay on the device before the gesture goes through and updates.  Any ideas what might be causing this?  This is on the new iPhone also so it shouldn't be processing speed.

Comment: Are you doing some hard drawings there? You need to specify where the time is actually wasting.

Comment: I'm using a lot of uibuttons on a grid to highlight where a user touches on the screen. In order to give a decent "resolution" the buttons are small (and many). Hence the pinch zoom interface. Is there another better way to do this?